# Proof by contradiction and the well ordering principle

Tags: proof-writing, well-orders

I have a question regarding proof by contradiction and the well ordering principle on integers.

Okay lets says for example an arbitrary value $p$ is a positive integer and which I assume is the smallest positive integer for some property.

Then lets say I find an arbitrary value $r$, also a positive integer, which I calculate to be less than $p$ for the same property. Then I have a contradiction.

So my question is how is this possible. Lets substitute $1$ for $p$ and it satisfies the property, then how can I find $r$ since there is no smaller positive integer? I'm not sure if $0$ is considered a positive integer but if it is then substitute $p$ for $0$.

Comment: Another term for this is proof by infinite descent. I don’t have time to write an answer but you may find something helpful here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent

Comment: It will also help to get more of a feel for the hypothetical nature of proofs by contradiction by studying other proofs by contradiction that might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the proof by contradiction is that you can find no such $r$. That's the contradiction. You assume something you want to be false, then prove something that can't be possible. It may be helpful to give a specific example of a proof that's confusing you.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107153/first-known-proof-of-sqrt-2-is-irrational-with-prime-factorization

Comment: See the answer using the well ordering principle

Comment: from the link sent

Comment: Yeah, so in that proof you assume that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Then using well ordering you can find a least $q$ such that $q\sqrt{2}$ is an integer. Then without assuming anything else, you can find $r < q$ a positive integer such that $r \sqrt{2}$ is a positive integer, which is a contradiction by minimality of $q$.

Comment: So the fact that an r can't actually be found is part of the contradiction. Am I correct?

Comment: The fact that r is less than q means that I can find an r. Yes? If so what if 1 is q and it satisfies the property that q times root 2 is a positive integer. How can I then find an r?

Comment: Its hypothetical that p = 1 satisfies the property.

Comment: Yes, the fact that $r$ can't actually be found is part of the contradiction. If $p = 1$ then you can't find such an $r$, yet in the proof we found such an $r$, which is a contradiction - exactly what we want.

Comment: Cool. Thank you.